# R write function excluding data

Tags: r

I am using the write function to store a dataset in r. This dataset is very large (15627918 objects of 3 variables). When I use the write function (write.table as a .txt file) however and open the file on my computer the file does not contain all this data. It usually contains about 1/4 of the rows but sometimes when I run it it is closer to 1/2 of the rows. (All columns appear it is only the rows that are missing.

"write.table(dataname, file = "dataname.txt", sep= "\t", row.names=F)"

Comment: How are you opening the file? There is no limit the the size of a CSV file as long as your computer has the disk space to create it. Are you trying to open it in Excel?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have ressolved the issue. Since it was such a large amount of data I had to wait a long time before all the data appeared in the file. If the file was opened before all the lines had been filled it would not fill in the rest. Once I ran the code and then waited a good length of time it worked.